# how to use std::accummulate in c++ to calculate sum cubes

Tags: c++, stl, range, std

Suppose I have a range where I want to calculate the sum of cubes of each element e.g. for `[1,2,3]` I want:

1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> = 36

How would I do this using `std::accummulate()`, where I would have to write my own binary function? I've got:

```
std::accummulate(iterator to beginning,
                 iterator to end of range,
                 0.0,
                 [](int i, int j) { return i*i*i + j*j*j; });
```

But this doesn't work for some reason.

The question came out weird, but in my return I'm just multiplying `i` and `j` with themselves 3 times and adding.

Answer (score 5):

As usual, [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is your friend.

Instead of adding the running sum and the new value, you should add the running sum to the cube of the new value.

```
std::accumulate(first, last, 0, [](int sum, int value) 
                 { return sum + (value*value*value); });
```

Comment: Could be better understood with transform_reduce: `std::transform_reduce(first, last, 0, std::plus<>{}, [](auto val) { return val*val*val; })`

Comment: Possibly, but the question was "How to use accumulate to ..."